# Make new folder from Vim command line in Windows gVim

Tags: vim, gvim

Can it be done?

I am editing a file, and I would like to copy it to a *new* folder. If I try `:w ~/Documents/new_folder/new_file.txt`, then I get `Can't open file for writing`.

So I try `:!mkdir ~/Documents/new_folder`, but I get the error (in a popup terminal window):

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c mkdir ~/Documents/new_folder
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows gvim uses Windows' cmd.exe to execute `:!` commands and cmd.exe does not understand `~` as an alias for `$HOME`. Also, cmd.exe accepts only `\` as a path separator, not `/`. Try instead

```
:cd ~
:!mkdir Documents\new_folder
```

Since `:cd` is a Vim internal command, Vim will correctly expand `~` itself.

[Edit: Added `!` in front of `mkdir` (typo), changed path separator from `/` to `\` (mistake) and added sentence about it.]

Comment: if I do `:mkdir ...`, then it doesn't know the command; if I do `:!mkdir ...`, then I get the same error as above.

Comment: @richardh: I fixed the answer to one that should actually work. The missing `!` was a typo. Some Windows commands accept either `/` or `\` as a path separator and I though cmd.exe was one of them. Apparently not.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, you don't need to switch the directory (although that is fewer key strokes)... So my original errors were using the `~` and using the wrong tabs.

Comment: FWIW, Windows API accepts both slashes internally, it's just `cmd` that tries to parse `/new_folder` as an option switch. (It worked this way even before MS-DOS had directories.)

Comment: `/` isn't treated as a switch character if one uses quotation marks, as in my answer.  (-:

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses backslashes for directory paths.
 Also, Windows uses %HOMEPATH% for the user's home directory instead of the unix-like ~.

Try

```
:!mkdir \%HOMEPATH\%\Documents\new_folder
```

Comment: that does it! Although typing `\%HOMEPATH\%` and losing tab completion are no fun. Thanks!

Comment: It's technically `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` - or `%USERPROFILE%` which is the same path most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing:

- **the `C` in the `/C` option that should have been passed to CMD.**  I'm presuming a transcription error on your part.
- **that `~` isn't part of the filesystem proper.**  It's Bourne-family/C-shell-family syntactic sugar.  It doesn't exist outwith those shells (and things that emulate their filesystem name semantics).

If you want the CMD command interpreter to expand the `USERPROFILE` environment variable (not `HOME` as on Unix/Linux, note) in a command line, [the correct syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc737438%28WS.10%29.aspx) is

```
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/new_folder"
```

Notice the quotation marks that will cope with directory names containing space characters.

Of course, in turn you'll have to escape the `%` characters to prevent vim from recognizing and processing them as *its own* peculiar command line metacharacters.

Comment: Thanks much! Good catch on me dropping the `/c` above; I'll fix. For some reason I thought that because gVim was doing tab-completion for me that Windows would take the backslashes and `~`.