# Vim ! before execute silent '!mkdir' what is it for?

Tags: linux, vim, editing

[Make new folder from Vim command line in Windows gVim](https://superuser.com/questions/297072/make-new-folder-from-vim-command-line-in-windows-gvim)

In this with the mkdir command a '!' is added in front of the command.

What does the '!' actually do?

Comment: This is basic, decades-old vi stuff; have you really not found any documentation?! If you're a total beginner, `vimtutor.bat` (comes with Vim) may introduce you to the absolute basics.

Comment: Also, Vim comes with an extensive documentation. Learn to use it. In this specific case, the answer is there: `:help !`.

Answer (score 1):

It tells VIM to run the command through a commandset:

[Vim Cookbook](http://www.oualline.com/vim-cook.html)

```
"The ! command tells Vim to run the text through UNIX command."
```

*Edit: as JGB's link mentions, not UNIX directly*

However, that is not always the case.  Different placements can result in different things, as you have probably seen.  You can see a lot of other options in this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094667/whats-the-use-of-the-exclamation-mark-in-vims-command-line) question/answer set. (things such as force, toggle, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The ! is for entering shell commands. In this case a command (mkdir) that would normally be entered at the windows command line.

More information available [on the VIM documentation site](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.2)